# Are there hinges that will accommodate 1.5 in thick cabinet doors? If so, would they solve the issue discussed below?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, remodeling, hinges

I'm adding a frame around my kitchen cabinet doors, using lengths of oak that are 3/4" thick x 2 1/2" wide.  The 3/4" thick frame makes the cabinet doors 1 1/2" thick, and when I reattached the hinged doors to the cabinets I realized this was not going to be so easy as I was going to have some trouble getting the doors to open 90°.  Is it possible to fix this without adjusting the spacing between doors?  Maybe using a special type of hinge?

Comment: I googled “thick cabinet door hinge”, you should also.

Comment: And add pictures to your posts to help us understand exactly what kind of hinges you're using.  There is a very wide variety.